# SQL stored procedure query to clear date field if NULL

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm not a SQL expert, but have a stored procedure query to insert a record into a table. I have a select call in my insert query to replace a NULL DateTime field to ''. But for some reason it doesn't work. The DateTime field is still NULL in the database table after the insert. Could someone look at the query below let me know if the select call to clear the DateTime field is valid to do in the same insert call.

```
CREATE PROC pCreate_DBQuery
( 
   @Message varchar(max),
   @DateTime smalldatetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime)
    VALUES (@Message, @DateTime)
    SELECT ISNULL(@ProcessedDateTime,'1900-01-01') AS [Changed Processed 
    Date]
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

This command

```
EXEC pCreate_DBQuery 'None', NULL
```

Table results from insert

```
None, NULL
```

Comment: You can't store `''` in column which is the datatype `date` (or `smalldatetime``datetime2`, etc). `''` isn't a date(time). This appears to be an xy question here; what is the real problem at hand?

Comment: if the datatype is DATETIME then you cant insert a '' value (quote quote, empty).

Comment: Why would you replace NULL at all? That does not make sense.

Comment: you can only replace it with a valid `SMALLDATETIME` value. Like: `SELECT ISNULL(@DateTime,'1900-01-01') AS [Changed Date]` Edit: note that `ISNULL` function already replaces null value with 2nd argument, the `REPLACE` is a redundant try in your query.

Comment: The replace in your Select is not affecting the record but only the displayed results of your query, you need an update maybe. But yet you need to have an actual datetime, if you have a problem with the field being null you can set it to the default min value : 1900-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: So many things wrong, sounds like an XY problem.   Why do you think you want to store `''` instead of NULL in your `DateTime` column?   There's probably a better way to do what you really want to do.

Comment: You should make us more clear your point. Your current code inserts 1 single record in a table `dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime)`, both fields taken from 2 parameters which are passed before execution (otherwise they are null). Then your 2 `SELECT` statements are useless. If your target is to insert a smalldatetime provided by @DateTime parameter, then you should avoid NULL exceptions by using something like: `INSERT INTO dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime)   VALUES (@Message, ISNULL(@DateTime, '1900-01-01'))`.

Comment: What is the point of the replace here? It makes no sense. If you want to default your date to 1900-01-01 then a simple ISNULL(@ProcessedDateTime, '') will be sufficient. The empty string will be converted to a datetime which will be 1900-01-01

Comment: Thanks B3S for your answer. I can just leave it NULL. So what if I was to change the NULL field and replace it w/ say '1900-01-01' by using
SELECT ISNULL(@ProcessedDateTime,'1900-01-01') AS [Changed Processed Date] it says it changes when the query is executed, but it doesn't get updated in the table. How would I change the stored procedure above to do so?

Comment: If you are looking to update an existing record in your table, then you should use `UPDATE` statement. BE CAREFUL: dont use it without an appropriate `WHERE` clause. For more help you should share the table structure (is it `dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime)`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REPLACE` doesn't work with `NULL`. If you want to insert the value `19000101` if the value `NULL` is passed you would need to do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime)
SELECT @Message, ISNULL(@DateTime,'19000101');
```

Personally, though, I would still think that `NULL` is better than the date `19000101`.

If you want an `UPDATE` then the syntax would be:

```
UPDATE dbo.TestTbl
SET DateTime = '19000101'
WHERE DateTime IS NULL;
```

Comment: The `INSERT` is followed by `VALUES`, and the @DateTime value is what he should put under `ISNULL` function i guess.

Comment: Good spot @B3S! (What I get for blindly copying the OP's code; whoops).

Comment: B3S, what do you mean by the 'INSERT is followed by VALUES', the VALUES statement cannot follow the INSERT, It must be before in the query otherwise it results in a error =) It must be like this INSERT INTO dbo.TestTbl(Message, DateTime) followed by
    VALUES (@Message, @DateTime) =)  All I want to know is where this statement SELECT ISNULL(@ProcessedDateTime,'1900-01-01') AS [Changed Processed Date] will go in the stored procedure query, so the table is properly updated w/ the replaced field if I decide to do it.

Comment: I realize the NULL is the best choice now, but just want to know how to change a field, if I need to later on when the stored procedure is called.

Comment: @Wildview I've added an `UPDATE` statement for your reference.

Comment: `INSERT` statement can be followed by `VALUES`: you should specify every row and every field for each row that will be inserted in a table. `INSERT` can also be followed by `SELECT` statement: in this case the resultset of that `SELECT` must contain all fields specified by `INSERT` or, if not specified, all table fields. Now lets say you want to `UPDATE` a field called `MyDate` in a table called `MyTable`: you dont actually need a stored procedure to do this. You can simply write an update statement using this kind of syntax: `UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = ISNULL(MyDate, '1900-01-01')`